# how do I send datagridview data to sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I tried to send datagridview data to sql server. I have logic layer and a data layer

```
  // calling logic layer 

  RecLogic.ProcessRecoveryData(dataGridView1.DataSource)
```

then i access that datasource from datalayer

```
//this is my logic class

public void ProcessRecoveryData(object dataSource)
{
    try
    {               
        new RecoveryData().ProcessRecoveryData(dataSource);
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlEx)
    {
        throw sqlEx;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

hen i access that datasource from logic layer

```
//this is my data class

 public void ProcessRecoveryData(object dataSource)
    {

        try
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon;
            SqlDataAdapter sqlAdp = new SqlDataAdapter();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.dataSource.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = "my_sp";              sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",dataGridView1.dataSource.Rows[i].Cells["text"].Value);    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",dataGridView1.dataSource.Rows[i].Cells["text"].Value);
                        sqlAdp.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
                    }                
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlEx)
            {
                throw sqlEx;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
                sqlCmd.Dispose();

            }
        }
```

how can i send datasource in data layer to sql?

Comment: Table-Valued Parameters may be useful here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/bb510489.aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a Table type and have a parameter of that type in your stored procedure......
eg
In SQL....

```
  CREATE TYPE myTableType AS table (
    categoryBridgeId uniqueIdentifier,
    denomination int,
    qty int
    );

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[My_Sproc] (@items myTableType READONLY,
etc
```

Then in C# you can pass a DataTable to the storred procedure...

```
..
var tblParam = new SqlParameter("@items", SqlDbType.Structured);
tblParam.Value = GetItemsAsDataTable(req);
tblParam.TypeName = "dbo.myTableType ";  
cmd.Parameters.Add(tblParam);
...

private static DataTable GetItemsAsDataTable(ECodeAddItemsToBasketRequest req)
{
  var result = new DataTable();
  result.Columns.Add("categoryBridgeId", typeof(Guid));
  result.Columns.Add("denomination", typeof(int));
  result.Columns.Add("qty", typeof(int));
  foreach (var item in req.ps)
  {
    Guid category = item.cid;
    int denomination = item.d;
    int qty = item.q;
    result.Rows.Add(category, denomination, qty);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Hope this helps - Good luck!

Comment: ???????
I'm sure it's available in the same language as you appear to be using for "ProcessRecoveryData"
and I am pretty sure SQL Server 2005 has types
The datatable is in c#